# Is it possible to change a domain controller's GUID?

Tags: active-directory, certificate, smartcard

I have a large number of separate Active Directory domains (~150) consisting of 2 server clusters that I need to setup for smart card login. To do this I will have to request ~300 domain controller certificates manually due to my environment. Needless to say that is a huge amount of manual effort and I am looking to script it.

To request a domain controller certificate you need three pieces of information: the certificate request, domain name and GUID. I can generate all of that information automatically but I cannot figure out how to change each domain controller's GUID to match the cert short of a direct ldap change. Does anyone know if that would work or would I break the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, never ever do this. The GUID is AD's means of locating/identifying a domain controller for replication. It's important that it remain unchanged (and most importantly, unique to each DC).

Could you setup the machines to trust a central CA and have that issue the machine certs automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately none of these machines have any sort of network connectivity to each other and I have to use a specific third party CA. Oh well it was a thought that I could save myself some pain. Thanks though.